# VBScript set IconLocation with commas in the file path name

Tags: vbscript

So I created this program that loops though all the lnk files in its folder and inserts an environmental variable into both the shortcut's target path and icon path. The problem is some of these target icons have a comma in the name, so when I use .IconLocation the file path cuts off after the comma and assumes the rest of the string is the icon index. Hence my question is how do you use .IconLocation and have a comma in the file path without it cutting of the rest of the string after the comma?

Comment: Solved my own problem in order for .IconLocation to not cut off the string you have to explicitly set the index at the send of the string. If you don’t do it explicitly it won’t work. Thus you end up with two commas in the string one for the path name and one for the index which you just set to zero.

Comment: Don’t forget to leave an answer, that way others will benefit from the solution. It might also help to [edit] the question and include a small sample of code that demonstrates the problem.